# subset data in SQL:

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider a table called records with the columns(name(TEXT), price(INT), color(TEXT), vehicletype(TEXT)).

```
 select name, price, color, vehicletype where
```

> "If it is a black sedan, I'm ready to pay 10,000, but if its red or
>   white, then no more than 8,000.  For any other color I won't above
>   7,000, except if its an SUV, in which case my budget is upto 15,000
>   for black one or upto 14,000 for any other color."

Answered this question using where clause with "and" and "or". Looking for a more efficient way to solve this.

Comment: What did you try to solve your home work?

Comment: I used a where clause: where (color = "black" and price <=10000) or (color in ("red", "white") and price <=8000) or (color not in ("black", "red", "white") and price <= 7000) so on..

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a zero effort homework dump.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try `UNION` Or `UNION ALL` E.g.

```
Select * from table where color = 'black' and price <= 10000
UNION
Select * from table where color in ('red', 'white') and price <= 8000
UNION
```

Etc.

Answer (score 0):

> If it is a black sedan, I'm ready to pay 10,000, but if its red or
>   white, then no more than 8,000. For any other color I won't above
>   7,000, except if its an SUV, in which case my budget is upto 15,000
>   for black one or upto 14,000 for any other color.

```
SELECT name, price, color, vehicletype FROM table
 WHERE (UPPER(vehicletype) = 'SEDAN'
   AND ((UPPER(color) = 'BLACK' AND price <= 10000)
    OR (UPPER(color) IN ('RED','WHITE') AND price <= 8000)
    OR (UPPER(color) NOT IN ('BLACK','RED','WHITE') AND price <= 7000)))
    OR (UPPER(vehicletype) = 'SUV'
   AND ((UPPER(color) = 'BLACK' AND price <= 15000)
    OR (UPPER(color) != 'BLACK' AND price <= 14000)))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response, I have answered the same. Looking for more efficient to write the same query.